# SAS:How to filter out using multiple keywords from a group

Tags: sas

I have a data that has activities each person performs during a season -

```
Name Season Activity
A   1   x
A   1   y
A   1   z
A   1   t
A   2   y
A   2   u
A   3   x
B   1   u
B   1   v
B   2   r
B   2   x
B   2   y
B   3   k
B   3   j
```

If a person has activity  x & y  in season 1 then I want all his rows for the first season to have a flag yes-

```
Name    Season  Disease Flag
A   1   x   Yes
A   1   y   Yes
A   1   z   Yes
A   1   t   Yes
A   2   y   No
A   2   u   No
A   3   x   No
```

similarly I have different disease combination for different seasons and activity. 
I have 5 activity variables ( activity 1- activity 5) and 30 ativity combinations for which I need to create 5 flags.
I am unable to write an efficient code for this.

The code I have come up with is --

```
CREATE TABLE activity_x AS                  
SELECT a.*
FROM table1 as a join (SELECT distinct person, season from table1 
where activity= 'x') as b
on a.person  = b.person and a.season= b.season
ORDER BY person, season;
QUIT;
```

This would give me a data-set with all information for person and seasons where atleast one activity in the season is x.

Similarly I would repeat for activity y and get a dataset.

Then find inner join of the two.
But issue is that the activity code combinations are very complex

```
Any one of this list    and     Any one of this list
a                                    r
b+c                                  m
d+c                                  n
s+c                                  o
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Add this information to the question `Here is the data that defines the combinations that need to be identified`.  Are the `activity1-5` combinations that go 'across' need to be located in the single activity column looking down the rows of each group?

Comment: You're asking too many questions at a time here. Simplify your question to be one specific question including what you have, what you want and what you've tried and you'll get an answer pretty quickly .

Answer (score 0):

Here's a double DOW-loop approach for the first part of your question:

```
data have;
input Name $ Season Activity $;
cards;
A   1   x
A   1   y
A   1   z
A   1   t
A   2   y
A   2   u
A   3   x
B   1   u
B   1   v
B   2   r
B   2   x
B   2   y
B   3   k
B   3   j
;
run;

data want;
 do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.Season);
  set have;
  by Name Season;
  if Activity = 'x' then __x_flag = 1;
  if Activity = 'y' then __y_flag = 1;
 end;
 do _n_ = 1 to _n_;
  set have;
  xy_flag = __x_flag and __y_flag;
  output;
 end;
 drop __:;
run;
```

You can generalise this quite easily to deal with whatever conditions you like - just create one flag per `Activity` value in the first loop and then combine them in the second loop.

This should perform much better than your SQL approach as it only makes a single pass through the data, rather than 1 query per value.